# Return whichever expression returns first

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

I have two different functions `f`, and `g` that compute the same result with different algorithms.  Sometimes one or the other takes a *long* time while the other terminates quickly.   I want to create a new function that runs each simultaneously and then returns the result from the first that finishes.

I want to create that function with a higher order function

```
h = firstresult(f, g)
```

What is the best way to accomplish this in Python?

I suspect that the solution involves threading.  I'd like to avoid discussion of the GIL.

Comment: You can also use `multiprocessing`, for example. Did you try anything and you are unhappy with the results ?

Comment: If your functions are computation-heavy and don't do I/O, then threading will not help, because of Python's GIL. Go for multiprocessing. Here's a good place to start: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now - unlike my suggestion on the other answer, this piece of code does exactly what you are requesting:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

import random
import time


def firstresult(func1, func2):
    queue = Queue()
    proc1 = Process(target=func1,args=(queue,))
    proc2 = Process(target=func2, args=(queue,))
    proc1.start();proc2.start()
    result = queue.get()
    proc1.terminate(); proc2.terminate()
    return result

def algo1(queue):
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0,1))
    queue.put("algo 1")

def algo2(queue):
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0,1))
    queue.put("algo 2")

print firstresult(algo1, algo2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use a [Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#queue-objects) for this. Start the threads and the first one which has a result ready writes to the queue.

### Code

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from Queue import Queue

def firstresult(*functions):
    queue = Queue()
    threads = [] 
    for f in functions:
        def thread_main():
            queue.put(f())
        thread = Thread(target=thread_main)
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()
    result = queue.get()
    return result

def slow():
    sleep(1)
    return 42 

def fast():
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print firstresult(slow, fast)
```

### Live demo

http://ideone.com/jzzZX2

### Notes

Stopping the threads is an entirely different topic. For this you need to add some `state` variable to the threads which needs to be checked in regular intervals. As I want to keep this example short I simply assumed that part and assumed that all workers get the time to finish their work even though the result is never read.

Skipping the discussion about the Gil as requested by the questioner. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Run each function in a new worker thread, the 2 worker threads send the result back to the main thread in a 1 item queue or something similar. When the main thread receives the result from the winner, it  kills (do python threads support kill yet? lol.) both worker threads to avoid wasting time (one function may take hours while the other only takes a second).

Replace the word thread with process if you want.

Comment: D'uh -- jsut read your answer after pastign the proof of concept code above. But indeed, this seens to be the "one obvious way to do it".  (One should not use threads, however - the GIL makes tehm useless for CPU bound operations like these)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run each function in another process (with multiprocessing) or in a different thread. 
If both are CPU bound, multithread won help much - exactly due to the GIL - 
so multiprocessing is the way.

If the return value is a pickleable (serializable) object, I have this decorator I created that simply runs the function in background, in another process:

https://bitbucket.org/jsbueno/lelo/src

It is not exactly what you want - as both are non-blocking and start executing right away. The tirck with this decorator is that it blocks (and waits for the function to complete) as when you try to *use* the return value.

But on the other hand - it is just a decorator that does all the work.